# Converting from globalized date/time format (maybe ISO8601) to SQL Server datetime type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, timezone, globalization

Is there a string format to represent a datetime that SQL will be able to parse and convert into another offset (EST -> UTC for example).

I have a string from the user such as:

```
declare @p1 varchar(50);
declare @utcDateTime datetime;

set @p1 = "2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:00";   -- could be ISO8601

-- what do I do here to convert @p1?

set @utcDateTime = -- should be "2009-06-26 18:30:00.000"
```

I want to be able to convert the string to its UTC equivalent and store it in a datetime field.  Such that:

```
select @ utcDateTime
```

should yield this:

```
"2009-06-26 18:30:00.000"
```

In other words, I want to store a datetime that has the value of '2009-06-26 18:30', given the first string.

Also, we must assume the server is not in the same timezone as the user (so we can't just detect the offset datediff(gettime(), getutctime()).

I have tried using convert(...) and cast(... as datetime) but with no luck.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: What's wrong with storing the data as a datetime?

Comment: The given string cannot be converted; SQL Server gives this error: "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Comment: "Could be ISO", or _is_ ISO? It would be better to pick one format.

Comment: I mean, I can tell the users which format to use - I would choose ISO 8601.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK here's my try at it - this was fun :-)

```
 DECLARE  @datestr varchar(100)

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+4:00'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:00'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+14:00'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+4:30'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:30'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )

SET @datestr = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+14:30'

SELECT @datestr, DATEADD(mi, -1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,25,1)+'1' AS int) *  
    DATEDIFF(mi,'1900-01-01', CAST(SUBSTRING(@datestr,26,5) as datetime)),   
    CAST(LEFT(@datestr,23) as datetime) )
```

Returns:

```
2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+4:00  2009-06-26 10:30:00.000

2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:00  2009-06-26 18:30:00.000

2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+14:00 2009-06-26 00:30:00.000

2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+4:30  2009-06-26 10:00:00.000

2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:30  2009-06-26 19:00:00.000

2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+14:30 2009-06-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Sweet!  This works!  I was hoping it wouldn't look so ugly, but whatever.  This also requires that the string be a certain length - but I'm validating the string pattern on the way in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

one way if you are using datetimes
run this in a window

```
declare @date varchar(100)
select @date = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000'

select dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,getdate(),getutcdate()),@date)
```

output
2009-06-26 18:30:00.000

better to just use getutcdate() all the time and store the users offset in his profile

SQL Server 2008 has new [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) data type which makes this much easier

now here is an answer that will work with the data you have (I added the 1/2 hour code also)

How the code works is explained here: [Adding time offsets passed in to a datetime to generate localized datetime](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/adding-time-offsets-passed-in-to-a-datet)

```
    declare @date varchar(100),@multiplier int

select @date = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+4:30'
select @multiplier = case when @date like '%+%' then -1 else 1 end


select dateadd(mi, @multiplier *convert(int,right(@date,2)),dateadd(hh
    ,-1 * convert(int,replace(substring(@date,patindex('%z%',@date)+ 1,3),':',''))
    ,left(@date,23)))
go


--2009-06-26 10:00:00.000

declare @date varchar(100),@multiplier int

select @date = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-4:30'
select @multiplier = case when @date like '%+%' then -1 else 1 end

select dateadd(mi, @multiplier *convert(int,right(@date,2)),dateadd(hh
    ,-1 * convert(int,replace(substring(@date,patindex('%z%',@date)+ 1,3),':',''))
    ,left(@date,23)))
go

--2009-06-26 19:00:00.000

declare @date varchar(100),@multiplier int

select @date = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z+14:30'
select @multiplier = case when @date like '%+%' then -1 else 1 end

select dateadd(mi, @multiplier *convert(int,right(@date,2)),dateadd(hh
    ,-1 * convert(int,replace(substring(@date,patindex('%z%',@date)+ 1,3),':',''))
    ,left(@date,23)))
go

--2009-06-26 01:00:00.000


declare @date varchar(100),@multiplier int
select @date = '2009-06-26 14:30:00.000Z-14:30'
select @multiplier = case when @date like '%+%' then -1 else 1 end

select dateadd(mi, @multiplier *convert(int,right(@date,2)),dateadd(hh
    ,-1 * convert(int,replace(substring(@date,patindex('%z%',@date)+ 1,3),':',''))
    ,left(@date,23)))
go

--2009-06-27 05:00:00.000
```